# I'm trying to disable a sub-license from a office365 E1 license

Tags: powershell, office365

I have a project where I need to disable the "EXCHANGE_S_STANDARD" under the office365 E1license. This will have to be done for more than 300 users. I have been trying to do this using PowerShell.

I was running 
`(Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName testuser@domain.com).Licenses[0].ServiceStatus[16]`, so I know that is the right serviceplan but still is not working and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
$License = "Domain:STANDARDPACK"
$LicenseOption = New-MsolLicenseOptions -AccountSkuId $License -DisabledPlans "EXCHANGE_S_STANDARD"
Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName testuser@Domain.com | Set-MsolUserLicense $LicenseOption
```

This is the error I'm getting.

```
Set-MsolUserLicense : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Microsoft.Online.Administration.LicenseOption'.
At line:3 char:58
+ ... cipalName testuser@domain.com | Set-MsolUserLicense $LicenseOption
+                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-MsolUserLicense], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.SetUserLicense
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `-LicenseOptions` parameter when you run `Set-MsolUserLicense`:

```
Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName testuser@Domain.com | Set-MsolUserLicense -LicenseOptions $LicenseOption
```

The positional parameter error means that the parameter has not been assigned a position number. If a position number is assigned, then the value passed to that parameter can be appended to the command without using the parameter name. The position numbers start with 0.

```
Function Example {
Param(
   [Parameter(Position=0)]
   [string]$Par1,
   [Parameter(Position=1)]
   [string]$Par2,
   [Parameter(Position=2)]
   [string]$Par3
)
$PSBoundParameters
}

Example "Value1" "Value2" "Value3" # Using Positions

Key  Value
---  -----
Par1 Value1
Par2 Value2
Par3 Value3

Example -Par1 "Value1" -Par2 "Value2" -Par3 "Value3" # Using Parameter Names

Key  Value
---  -----
Par1 Value1
Par2 Value2
Par3 Value3
```

However, do notice that if you mix using and not using parameter names with your positional parameters, PowerShell will assign the unnamed values in the order of the positional parameters that do not have assignments:

```
Example "Value3" "Value2" -Par1 "Value1"

Key  Value
---  -----
Par1 Value1
Par2 Value3
Par3 Value2
```

Notice how `-Par1` got `Value1` using the named parameter. But `$Par2` got `Value3` and `$Par3` got `Value2` using positions. This is because the parameter at position 0 already got an assignment. Positions 1 and 2 were left with no named assignments. So the first unnamed parameter value went to the parameter with the lowest available position number.